# jQuery dataTables - "sDom" is removing the css style from the datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I have used datatable to show my record and it is working fine as :

```
 table = $(".jqueryDataTable").dataTable( {

            "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
                  alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation in table.' );
                  this.fnHideEmptyColumns(this);
                  $('#lblReportHeader').html(reportHeader);
                  $('#lblFromDate').html(fromDateHeader);
                  $('#lblToDate').html(fromToHeader);
                  $('#tblReportHeader').show();
                },
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bRetrieve": true, 
                "bDestroy": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "./getReportDetails",
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
                    newData=aoData;
                    newData.push( { "name": "reportType", "value": reportType }, { "name": "reportSubType", "value": reportSubType}, { "name": "fromDate", "value": fromDate}, { "name": "toDate", "value": toDate});
                },
                "aoColumns": [
                                { "mData": "username", "sTitle": "username"},
                                { "mData": "transferType", "sTitle": "transferType"},
                                { "mData": "fromAccount", "sTitle": "fromAccount"},
                                { "mData": "toAccount", "sTitle": "toAccount"},
                                { "mData": "amount", "sTitle": "amount"},
                                { "mData": "currency", "sTitle": "currency"},
                                { "mData": "transferDate", "sTitle": "transferDate"},
                                { "mData": "creditDebitFlag", "sTitle": "creditDebitFlag"},
                                { "mData": "fromAccountType", "sTitle": "fromAccountType"},
                                { "mData": "toAccountType", "sTitle": "toAccountType"},
                                { "mData": "impsChannelType", "sTitle": "impsChannelType"},
                                { "mData": "impsTranType", "sTitle": "impsTranType"},
                                { "mData": "IFSCCode", "sTitle": "IFSCCode"},
                                { "mData": "narration", "sTitle": "narration"},
                                { "mData": "customerID", "sTitle": "customerID"},
                                { "mData": "customerName", "sTitle": "customerName"},
                                { "mData": "fromMMID", "sTitle": "fromMMID"},
                                { "mData": "fromMobileNo", "sTitle": "fromMobileNo"},
                                { "mData": "toMMID", "sTitle": "toMMID"},
                                { "mData": "toMobileNo", "sTitle": "toMobileNo"},
                                { "mData": "paymentType", "sTitle": "paymentType"},
                                { "mData": "transReferenceId", "sTitle": "transReferenceId"},
                                { "mData": "transactionStatus", "sTitle": "transactionStatus"}
                    ]
            } );
```

[image]

Then there was requirement to export the datatable into export so I took reference from : [datatable export](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/simple.html). So I added `"sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip'` in the code.

After adding "sDom" my css is not working.
Can anyone tell me what is the wrong in my code ?

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing any reference to `tableTools` in the initialisation code... could that be the problem?

Comment: Because he's using v1.9 (`dataTable` in the init code instead of `DataTable` )

Comment: In the given reference tableTools in not intialized,  markpsmith

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/simple.html  ?